# Why rollback is not working as expected in JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/python", "root", "vikalp");
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        try(Statement cursor = connection.createStatement()){
            cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE sa(id int)");
        }
        connection.rollback();

    }
}
```

Here python is my database name why the rollback doesn't happen?
How to make it rollback?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` is a DDL statement, and DDL statements are not transactional. They happen immediately and are not affected by rollbacks.

Comment: But in SQL we can make it. by using BEGIN TRANSACTION

Comment: In real project I am using multiple statemnt therefore I cannot make every statement starting with BEGIN as I asked user whether he wants autoCommit or not

Comment: You can write `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before a DDL-statement in SQL, but it won't have any effect.

Comment: Got your point but is there any way to make DDL in transaction with multiple statements.
Should I use savepoint?

Comment: No.  There isn't a way to do that.  At least, not with MySQL.